# Is there a way to add the ']' special character in my regex, when it normally ends my proposition?

Tags: javascript, regex, joi

I am trying to fit ']' into my regex that lets any string pass as long as it doesn't have a certain set of special characters. However, the IDE shows me that it ends the expression:

```
message: Joi.string().regex(/^[^<>#*=+^}[]+$/).required()
//current working code


message: Joi.string().regex(/^[^<>#*=+^}[]]+$/).required()
//what I am trying to add
```

Comment: use a backslash to escape it \

Comment: well you need to escape it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping

Comment: What if you escape the square bracket? `/^[^<>#*=+^}[\]]+$/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape special character using \

So you can use:
`(/^[^<>#*=+^}[\]]+$/)`
which will escape the first ] allowing it to be viewed as a regular symbol.

If you are new to regular expressions, try regex101.com. It does a good job of breaking them down for you.

Comment: Alright thank you, I did that but for some reason my IDE did not register it, so I thought it didn't work like that.

Comment: Depending on where you're working you might have to \\ double escape. I have to do that in VS Code because of it's formatting defaults.